# アプリケーション内でのトーストライクな通知の作り方

Tags: c#, wpf

WPFアプリケーション内で，Windows8以降のトーストのような通知を出したいです。
適当なライブラリや参考サイトを教えてください。
下記URLの動画のようなイメージなのですが，ロシア語で参考資料もないため利用できていません。

[作成したい通知のイメージ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mK1xbTA1F_A)

Comment: 質問者さんはもう訪れていないようですが、こんなので代替できるかも。[ウィンドウの動きに追従するPopupコントロールを作る](http://sourcechord.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/10/25/205036)

Comment: こんなのも見つけました。[Federerer/Notifications.Wpf](https://github.com/Federerer/Notifications.Wpf), [WPFでイケてる通知(Notification)表示の実装を拝借(Windowsアプリ)](http://urusulambda.com/2018/10/10/wpf%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B1%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5notification%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%82%92%E6%8B%9D%E5%80%9Fwindows%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA/)

Answer (score 1):

下記、いかがでしょうか。よろしければどうぞ。

[非.NET4.5でもトースト通知](http://8thway.blogspot.jp/2014/02/notdotnet45-toast.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。残念ながら，WindowsAPIを叩くトースト通知ではなく，アプリケーション内に表示できるトースト通知のような通知方法を探しています。

Answer (score 0):

最近になってWPFから`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications`を呼び出すことで簡単にトースト通知を実装できるようになりました。

私が.NET Framework 4.6.1で実装した手順は以下の通りです。
[.NET5のWPFアプリでインタラクティブなトースト通知を実装する](https://qiita.com/ambleside138/items/2a5ae64afcf094261fa1)を参考にしました。

1. WPFの画面を作成する
2. NuGetで`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications`を検索する
3. 上記で該当したライブラリをインスト―ルする

   - インストールにあたっての注意点は[公式の手順](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast#step-1-install-nuget-package)から注記の「重要」欄を参照のこと
   - ライブラリバージョン7.0.2時点では.NET Framework 4.6.1以降に対応
   - .NET Core 3.0 WPF アプリは .NET Core 3.1 に更新すること
   - .NETバージョン 5のアプリではTargetFrameworkを`net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0`に変更すること
   - PackageReference形式に移行しないとWindows 10 SDK が正しく参照されない

     - 「Must use PackageReference」とエラー表示される場合、下記手順でPackageReferenceに移行する
     - ソリューションエクスプローラーから「参照」を右クリック
     - 「packages.configをPackageReferenceに移行する」をクリック
     - 「OK」をクリック
4. トーストする.csファイルに`using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;`を追加する
5. 下記のように[ToastContentBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastcontentbuilder)を呼び出す

```
private void ToastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new ToastContentBuilder()
        .AddText("My Toast")
        .AddText("Hello Toast!")
        .Show();
}
```

[image: 実行時のスクリーンショット]

Comment: @dai hira さんの要望である「アプリケーション内に表示できるトースト」の要件は満たしていませんでした…。